# jvectormap markers

Tags: javascript, jquery, jvectormap

I'm using jvectormap to show the locations of alumni related to the business I work with. Is there a solution to add links to markers? By that I mean for each individual marker, I am aware you can use this code to link all markers to one URL (as an example):

```
 onMarkerClick: function (event, code){
   var url = "http://www.google.com";
   $(location).attr('href',url);
 },
```

I've arranged my markers like this: `"US": {latLng: [38.90, -98.45], name: 'United States of America'}`, if this makes any difference.

I'm looking to use a unique URL for **each** marker. So USA links to a page dedicated for the USA for example. Currently I am able to link all markers to a single URL using the above code, it's when I try doing more than one country that I run into issues.

Thanks in advance,

Tom.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this

```
onMarkerSelected: function(){
   // do what you need to do here.
}
```

Example is here: 
http://jvectormap.com/examples/regions-selection/

In your marker add the URL:

```
"US": {latLng: [38.90, -98.45], name: 'United States of America', weburl : "/blah/foo"}
```

then when you have your function:

```
onMarkerClick: function(events, index) {
    $(location).attr('href', markers[index].weburl);
}
```

markers being your array of markers.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your quick response. How would I go about adding more than 1 URL for the marker? I've looked at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14713009/jvector-map-how-to-add-and-get-link-from-marker/14713235#14713235 and it doesn't seem to work, yet anyway. Forgive me, I'm a jquery / javascript noob!

Comment: How do you plan to use the 2 URLs per marker - where do you want to go to the first or second or you want to make a menu? Also, what doesn't work in the example you referenced?

Comment: If you use the example in the link you provided instead of weburl : "/blah/foo" you could make an array of URLs. And then use them as you see fit.

Comment: Thanks for your help, think I've sussed it out now with your help!

Comment: Updated the question, I don't think I was necessarily clear as I'm still stumbling into problems!