# Add href link to Map Marker

Tags: jquery

I am using this awesome map script

http://jvectormap.com/examples/markers-world/

The particular example adds markers on the map..

```
 jQuery(function(){
  jQuery('#elitemap').vectorMap({
    map: 'world_mill_en',
    scaleColors: ['#C8EEFF', '#0071A4'],
    normalizeFunction: 'polynomial',
    hoverOpacity: 0.7,
    hoverColor: false,
    markerStyle: {
      initial: {
        fill: '#e7a60a',
        stroke: '#0a0c19'
      }
    },
    backgroundColor: '#111111',
    markers: [
      {latLng: [41.90, 12.45], name: 'Vatican City', weburl : "/blah/foo" },
      {latLng: [43.73, 7.41], name: 'Monaco'},
      {latLng: [-0.52, 166.93], name: 'Nauru'},
      {latLng: [-8.51, 179.21], name: 'Tuvalu'},
      {latLng: [43.93, 12.46], name: 'San Marino'},
      {latLng: [47.14, 9.52], name: 'Liechtenstein'},
      {latLng: [7.11, 171.06], name: 'Marshall Islands'},
      {latLng: [17.3, -62.73], name: 'Saint Kitts and Nevis'},
      {latLng: [3.2, 73.22], name: 'Maldives'},
      {latLng: [35.88, 14.5], name: 'Malta'},
      {latLng: [12.05, -61.75], name: 'Grenada'},
      {latLng: [13.16, -61.23], name: 'Saint Vincent and the Grenadines'},
      {latLng: [13.16, -59.55], name: 'Barbados'},
      {latLng: [17.11, -61.85], name: 'Antigua and Barbuda'},
      {latLng: [-4.61, 55.45], name: 'Seychelles'},
      {latLng: [7.35, 134.46], name: 'Palau'},
      {latLng: [42.5, 1.51], name: 'Andorra'},
      {latLng: [14.01, -60.98], name: 'Saint Lucia'},
      {latLng: [6.91, 158.18], name: 'Federated States of Micronesia'},
      {latLng: [1.3, 103.8], name: 'Singapore'},
      {latLng: [0.33, 6.73], name: 'São Tomé and Príncipe'}
    ],
    onMarkerClick: function(events, index) {
    jQuery(location).attr('href', markers[index].weburl);
}
  });
});
```

I am looking to add an href link on each marker. I have done this for Vatican City above but nothing happens when i click on the marker..

Comment: this has already been answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14733360/jvectormap-markers

Comment: jvector map is not adding links(<a> tags) to the markers. Instead they are just Circles(<circle> tag) which don't have link functionality. jvector provides api to handle click event for the markers. You can do redirection in jvector onMarkerSelected event.

Comment: ok i have updated my question & code based on the link by mfreitas but still nothing happens when clicking on the marker..