# JVectorMap Javascript Link

Tags: javascript, jvectormap

Im using jvectormap to create a map and im trying to add links to the pins to link off to websites. Ive tried a few different things but nothing seems to be working. I currently have this:

$(function(){

```
var markers = [
    { latLng: [-35.727014, 174.320861], name: "Whangarei", image: 'pin.png', style: {image: 'themes/startertoplight/img/pin.png'} },
];

/* map parameters */
var wrld = {
        map: 'nz_mill_en',
        backgroundColor: '#28343B',
        onRegionClick: function(event, code) {
    if (code === 'Whangarei') {
        window.location = 'http://www.google.com'
    }
    },
        zoomButtons: false,
        zoomOnScroll: false,
        focusOn: {
            x: 0.3,
            y: 0.7,
            scale: 3
        },
        markerStyle: {
            initial: {
                fill: '#F8E23B',
                stroke: '#383f47'
            }
        },
        markers: markers,

};

$('#nz-map').vectorMap(wrld);
```

});

Any idea how i can get this to work? Thanks

Comment: And did you search -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14713009/jvector-map-how-to-add-and-get-link-from-marker

Comment: yeah i did try that but i was getting this error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ) when adding  onMarkerClick: function(events, index,)alert(markers[index].weburl); },

Comment: Check your syntax. You're missing a `{`.